# Why does "want" catenate with a nominal plus to-infinitive whereas "insist" does not?

Tags: grammar

Why can't you say:

> "I insist you to do that!"

After all, you can say:

> "I want you to do that!"

What's the difference between these two verbs, that they need to be used in sentences with different structures?

Comment: Nobody says "I insist you to do that." They might say "I insist *that you do* that."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

*Insist* is an intransitive verb. You can’t *insist something* or *insist someone*. You can only insist, and then say what it is you insist, using a clause beginning with *that*.

*Want* is a transitive verb. You can *want something* and even *want someone*. That’s why we can say *I want you*. That’s a complete sentence, but alone it means something rather intimate. That, however, isn’t the case when it’s followed by the plain form of the verb preceded by the particle *to* in your example.

Comment: You should change your answer. I insist upon it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no preposition in your grammatical sentence (the second one) – that's the infinitive-marker *to* (which looks exactly the same as the preposition *to*, though). I've edited the question accordingly.

If you look up catenative verbs (eg at [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs)), you will see the various ways different verbs catenate – some with an *-ing* form, some with a bare infinitive (like *go* in the US), some with a *to*-infinitive (like *want*, *desire*). *Help* accepts either a bare infinitive or a to-infinitive most of the time! Some verbs have different meanings with different forms of catenation, eg:

> He forgot putting the light on.
>   He forgot to put the light on.

And, further to the cited article: some verbs give rise to catenations that can (eg *want*) or must (eg *cause*) include a direct object. This is called the complex catenative construction (mentioned in [chapter 14 of *CGEL*](http://www.cambridge.org/assets/linguistics/cgel/chap14_contents.pdf)):

> I want to drive to London tomorrow.
>   I want **John** to drive to London tomorrow.
>   It caused **John** to have a sleepless night.

(Notice that the second *to*'s in the first two of these sentences are indeed examples of the preposition)

However, *insist* **doesn't** catenate. What we have here is a reduced that-clause:

> I insist (that) you do it.