# Does the verb “enable” take a bare-infinitive complement like “let” or a to-infinitive complement like “allow”?

Tags: grammaticality, bare-infinitive, predicate-frames, catenative-verbs

How can you predict which verbs take which type of infinitive as their complements? For example, is the *to* before *open* here mandatory, forbidden, or optional?

> - The Gold Monetization Scheme **will be revamped to enable people open** a hassle-free gold deposit account.
> - The Gold Monetization Scheme **will be revamped to enable people *to* open** a hassle-free gold deposit account.

In other words, does the verb *enable*:

1. take only a bare-infinitive complement the way *let* does?
2. take only a *to*-infinitive complement the way *allow* does?
3. take an optional *to* before its infinitive complement the way *help* does?

How can you tell which verb does which thing?

Comment: *Enable*requires *to*. I suspect it's the kind of thing you just have to learn one word at a time (*assist*, for example, would probably take something like ***with opening*** rather than any infinitive), but I'm curious to see if other folks know of a rule I've never noticed.

Comment: Answered at [Why does "want" catenate with a nominal plus to-infinitive whereas "insist" does not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103486/why-does-want-catenate-with-a-nominal-plus-to-infinitive-whereas-insist-does). There are lists showing various catenation patterns and the verbs displaying them at the linked Wiktionary article. // I have a list of 318 catenating verbs; 'enable' ticks only the {complex} + {to-infinitive} box. _This enabled the early pioneers to survive._